# How to handle user clicks local notification on Xamarin iOS when the user turns off app?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

My app receives notification and displays local [User Notification](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos).

[image: local notification] [image: click_open_notification]

When the user turns off this app and clicks to this local notification.

I want to handle event which opens this local notification.

I tried the link below:

[Handle local notification tap Xamarin Forms iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52229624/handle-local-notification-tap-xamarin-forms-ios)

But method **ReceivedLocalNotification()** doesn't seem to work (I tried showing an alert, but the Alert does not display.)

And I tried showing an alert in method **DidReceiveRemoteNotification()**

like [Xamarin.iOS - Red & Green Notifications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios12-redgreennotifications/) example, but I can't handle event "**user clicks local notification when the application is turned off**".

This is my code:

```
        [Export("userNotificationCenter:didReceiveNotificationResponse:withCompletionHandler:")]
    public void DidReceiveNotificationResponse(UNUserNotificationCenter center, UNNotificationResponse response, System.Action completionHandler)
    {
        // Show Alert 
        var alert = new UIAlertView()
        {
            Title = "LocalNotification",
            Message = $"Content: Method DidReceiveNotificationResponse()"
        };
        alert.AddButton("OK");
        alert.Show();

        if (response.IsDefaultAction)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ACTION: Default");
        }
        if (response.IsDismissAction)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ACTION: Dismiss");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"ACTION: {response.ActionIdentifier}");
        }

        completionHandler();
    }
```

Please help me!

How to handle event "**user clicks local notification when the application is turned off**"?
I'm testing on ios 12.4 and ios 13.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check inside your `AppDelegate.cs` inside the `FinishedLaunching` override for the options being passed into the app. It will contain the push notification info.

```
UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = new UserNotificationCenterDelegate();

if (options != null)
{
    if (options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey))
    {
        NSDictionary dic = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey] as NSDictionary;

        // decide what to do with push info here
    }

    Console.WriteLine($"Startup: {nameof(AppDelegate.FinishedLaunching)} : {nameof(options)} {options}");
}
```

You might also want to look at `UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate` to better handle you push notifications if you are using ios 10+. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#handling-foreground-app-notifications

Comment: I read document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/user-notifications/enhanced-user-notifications?tabs=macos#handling-foreground-app-notifications and I know your code will Watch for notifications while the app is active. But my case is when the user turns off the app and they open notification when the app turns off.

Comment: @HuuBaoNguyen If you look at the code you have to the the OPTIONS inside the FinishedLaunching for the key UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey. That gets populated when the app is turned off.

Comment: It works with option `options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey)`